# SQL Server 2012 select sum of multiple id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For example, I have a device ID of "001" each device ID has a column called total I want to retrieve only the SUM total of each device Id. How to do this please ?

```
SELECT
    SUM(TicketSales.TotalPrice) AS expr1
FROM 
    dbo.TicketSales,dbo.[Transaction]
WHERE 
    TicketSales.DeviceID = 'mapa001'
    AND SUM(TicketSales.TotalPrice) AS expr2
 FROM 
     dbo.TicketSales ,dbo.[Transaction]
 WHERE 
     TicketSales.DeviceID = 'mapa002'
```

Comment: You've tagged this question VB.NET and nothing else but the question is purely about SQL.  Please use relevant tags and ONLY relevant tags.

Comment: You need to select the device ID column and the `SUM` of the total column and then `GROUP BY` the device ID column. Do some reading about aggregate functions and you'll learn that you need to group by the columns that are not aggregated.

Comment: sorry about that, im working on vb.net and sql server. . any answer for the question ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what language you're building your application in. The SQL code you execute against the database will be the same regardless. As for answers, I told you what to do. The documentation for the `SUM` function even has code examples that demonstrate what I said. Start thinking about what you can do for yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but read some sql tutorials, these are the basics:

```
SELECT SUM(TicketSales.TotalPrice) AS expr1
FROM dbo.TicketSales
GROUP BY TicketSales.DeviceID
```

Comment: Add `WHERE TicketSales.DeviceID in ('mapa001', 'mapa002')`